# MVC Click button refresh view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, onclick

in MVC I have the simplest view. I added a button. The job of this button is to simply alert ("text").

```
<button id="btn-test" onClick="alert( 'test')">test</button>
```

or this javascript

```
 $("#btn-refresh").click(function () {
        //      refreshScheduler()
        alert("SSSSSSSS");
        return false;
    });
```

when the alert is closed the view refreshes!!!.
I do not want to refresh the page.
What should I do so that the execution of a click would only execute with anyview refresh ?
I do not need nor have patialviews nor target.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure but if your button was submit button,The page would be refreshed. Could you try input button.

    <input type="button" id="btn-test" value="test"/>

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I can see:

- Remove the onClick event from the button, and
- the selector for the jQuery click handler is incorrect it should be #btn-test and not #btn-refresh for instance

  $("#btn-test").click(function (e) {
          //      refreshScheduler()
          alert("SSSSSSSS");
          e.preventDefault();
      });